# How to implement showing 1-10 of 20 within bootpag pagination plugin

Tags: jquery, pagination

Im trying to look for a way to show the results count with my pagination. 
Viewing 1-5 of 22 which changes based on what page of results they are viewing.
Im using bootpag with ajax to return my results.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// init bootpag
    $('.pagination').bootpag({
        total: ${myOrdersData.totalNumberOfPages},
        maxVisible: 5,
        leaps: true,
        firstLastUse: true,
        first: '←',
        last: '→',
        wrapClass: 'pagination',
        activeClass: 'active',
        disabledClass: 'disabled',
        nextClass: 'next',
        prevClass: 'prev',
        lastClass: 'last',
        firstClass: 'first'


    }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){
      $.ajax({
       url: "ordersByPageNumber?pageNumber="+num,

      }).done(function(data) {
       $("#previousOrders").html( data );
      });


    });


  });
```